# Show all git-lfs files on a branch (working tree)

Tags: git, git-lfs

**How can i show all git-lfs files on a branch (working tree)?**

Before pushing to the repo i want to makes sure that the files are tracked by git-lfs and not normal git

Answer (score 0):

**Show all files on the working tree** with the following command:

```
git lfs ls-files
```

Additional information for the files can be displayed with parameter "-d"

```
git lfs ls-files -d
```

[git lfs ls-files - offical documentation](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-ls-files.1.ronn)